# logging EXPLAIN output of slow queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, explain

I am trying to understand if there is functionality like auto_explain in PostgreSQL for MySQL. Specifically, I am interested in logging the query plan (not just the query) for all slow queries in MySQL.

Is there any documentation on whether this is possible or not?

Comment: Please post results of SELECT @@version; so we know which flavor and version your instance is running.  Not all versions/options have the same possibilities.

Comment: @WilsonHauck version is no bar. I have complete freedom to choose whatever version I like.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has [log_slow_extra](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_slow_extra) which includes some session status variables per [this manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html), however its not equivalent to an [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html).

If you are using MariaDB then [EXPLAIN in the Slow Query Log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-in-the-slow-query-log/) is possible with [log-slow-verbosity=query_plan,explain](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#log_slow_verbosity)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have a feature to EXPLAIN all the queries in the slow query log as far as I know. This would be risky to do during logging, because some queries can be costly to the server even if you only do an EXPLAIN report (for example, if the query has a derived table subquery, the subquery is executed during the EXPLAIN).

I usually use the free [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html) tool to aggregate my slow query log.

That tool has an option [--explain](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html#cmdoption-pt-query-digest-explain) which makes it run EXPLAIN once for each query type in the report, and you can direct it to produce the EXPLAIN report on any MySQL instance you choose, so it doesn't necessarily have to be your production server.